# when clicked on imageurl in infowindows(google maps) it should open the image in webpage

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

The imageurl is displayed in infowindows of googlemaps. When clicked on the link the image must open in tab. The imageurl is retrieved from firebase database. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an callback event provided by Google to listen to InfoWindow click event. This is a map wide event and not marker wide. For every infoWindow click you will get callback along with Marker object using which you can differentiate and do required functioning.

[GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener)

Events are delivered in following callback.

```
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Info window clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

In this function then you can get the url from marker object and then load it in a webview or chrome or whatever the requirement.

Comment: if my answer helped then dont forget to upvote/accept it :)

Comment: actually i did upvote. but my reputation is not that high for public to view :) :)